# calculator program in android studio

Tags: compiler-errors

Getting this error when trying to compile my program in android studio:

Caused by: org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable

I already increased the targetSDK and compileSDK to 33